# Flutter: showDatePicker firstdate and lastdate from same week

Tags: flutter

I am trying to give user an option to select date between 7 days.
Like today is 2nd March then user can select any date before 10th March.

My current code is showing first date as 01/01/03 i am not sure why it is giving me this date.

Here is the code.

```
_pickedDate() async {
    rescheduleddate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().day + 1),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().day + 7),
      initialDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().day + 1),
    );

    if (rescheduleddate != null) {
      setState(() {
        pickeddate = rescheduleddate;
      });
    }
  }
```

I am not sure what am i doing wrong because if i add year instead of day then it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this one.

```
_pickedDate() async {
    rescheduleddate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 1)),
      lastDate: DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 7)), 
      initialDate: DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 1)), 
    );

    if (rescheduleddate != null) {
      setState(() {
        pickeddate = rescheduleddate;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that you aren't properly adding a duration to the current DateTime object. By calling `.day` you are just getting the number of the day as an integer, which you're then trying to plug back into a new DatePicker as an argument. For example, if today is March 2nd, `DateTime.now().day` would return 2, so your `firstDate` value is currently trying to evaluate what `DateTime(3)` is (if you inspect the DateTime function, the first argument is the year as an integer, so it's setting the date to 01/01/03). Try doing this:

```
rescheduleddate = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  firstDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7)),
  initialDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)),
);
```